# Assign three cores to doMC workers

Tags: r, macos, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

When I write the following command it tells me:

```
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 1
```

I want to assign 3 cores to my worker. How's that possible in RStudio?

Comment: Are you sure those aren't assigned as needed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read somewhere that no matter how many cores your computer has, RStudio assigns only 1 by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `R` just assigns 1 worker to your task. You have to use the following command to register more than 1 worker:

```
> registerDoMC(3)
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 3
```

I used these commands from [this manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf).